# MVC3 - Authenticate with SQL Server Accounts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, authentication

I couldn't find anything useful to this problem and I never used authentication in a web application before. So anything with / without cookies is new for me.

We've got an existing (non-web-)program using SQL Server accounts for authentication. Now, I want to do the same with my MVC3 project.

Every user has the same rights inside the database. The (non-web-)program handles the rights itself. After logging in successful (with an SQL account), the login name is mapped to an entity in the database from which one can get the users ID and handle the right management. If the user "admin" is logged in, he gets the ID 4711 and will see some more input fields etc. while other users have less rights.

Is this possible?

Besides that: What's the best approach to store the authentication and how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.Net in general (not specific to MVC) has a builtin way to manage authentication.

It's done through MembershipProvider, RoleProvider and PrincipalProvider. You can google those for more details.

In your scenario, where you have to check user credentials against an existing schema, you could simply implement your own custom MembershipProvider (and, if needed, RoleProvider and/or PrincipalProvider) deriving from the base class.

Inside your custom provider you'll implement the signature methods with your domain specific code.

Lastly, you just register your custom provider to be the default in the web.config and you're set. Your app can use the default Membership API to authenticate users and manager credentials.

Comment: I read about the providers in the book "Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework", but couln't get used to it. The thing is: The credentials are not in a schema. They are the SQL Server accounts itself. And I don't know how to use them for authentication. Or did I get your answer wrong?

Comment: Well, yes, you got it wrong :) The MembershipProvider is just a base class: you derive from it, so you have all the method signatures to implement. Inside those methods you can write whatever code you need. It doesn't have to be a query on the db, it can be anything. In your case, you'll write code to interact with the sql server accounts. As long as you respect the base class contract, you're fine.

Comment: Ah, thank you. "In your case, you'll write code to interact with the sql server accounts". That's the point. I have not a single clue how to do that (and then implement it into the global.asax & store it with a cookie or anything...). Do you know any good starting point?

Comment: You don't have to take care manually of the cookie or anything else. Once you implement the provider and set it as default membershipprovider in web.config, the .net pipeline will use that everytime the application tries to interact with the membership. It will handle cookies, etc. For the specific code to read sql users, I think you should ask a different question, since it's not the point of this question, as it is posed.

Answer (score 0):

If your DB structure is already decided on, you can write your own MembershipProvider that accesses your database (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WSSecurityProvider.aspx).

If you are flexible on the DB structure, you can use ASP.NET's built-in SqlMembershipProvider (see http://codehighstreet.com/Articles/overview_of_membership_and_installing_sql_membership_provider-part_1/overview_of_membership_and_installing_sql_membership_provider-part_1.aspx). You then have to run a SQL script that creates the tables and indexes for you. This works in MVC 3.

Comment: Hi, same as Matteos Moscas answer: I read about the providers in the book "Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework", but couln't get used to it. The thing is: The credentials are not in a schema. They are the SQL Server accounts itself. And I don't know how to use them for authentication. Or did I get your answer wrong?