# Work with SQL Server accounts (2005 & 2008)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, authentication

I'm writing a MVC application which has to use SQL Server accounts to authenticate. I want to use `MembershipProvider`, `RoleProvider` and `PrincipalProvider` for doing that (that's here: [MVC3 - Authenticate with SQL Server Accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505664/mvc3-authenticate-with-sql-server-accounts)).

Now my question is: how do I work with SQL Server accounts to authenticate against via C#? I don't know where to start and how complicated that is (together with MVC3). Could someone provide an example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The way your ASP.NET application will talk to the database will be through database logins/users.  On SQL Server you will create a login as such:

```
create login YourWebLogin with password = 'p@ssw0rd'
go
```

That is a basic login that can really do nothing (research server permissions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186717.aspx)).  Then you'd create a SQL Server user off of this login, like so:

```
use YourASPNETDb
go

create user YourWebUser for login YourWebLogin
go
```

Now you have the security context to access `YourASPNETDb` with a SQL Server user, through the context of a SQL Server login.  (research database permissions [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1718/database-level-permissions-for-sql-server-2005-and-2008/))

Your ASP.NET MVC application will access the database through your login/user, and this connection information will be stored in a connection string.  This is a typical SQL Server connection string:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Your Membership/Role Providers will utilize this connection string with your correct credentials to gain access to your database.

This is just a high-level view of how everything works together.  There are a few moving parts, but this should get you started.

Comment: Hi, I just forgot some infos. The SQL accounts are already there (I don't have to create or delete any of them) and all of them have "full rights". Their rights are managed with a database table according to the SQL user who is logged in. I don't know, if this is possible?!

Comment: @Sleepwalker if the login/user is already created with sufficient permissions, and you know the credentials of the login then just construct and use the connection string as in my post.

Comment: That is a good point. But how can I create dynamic connection string for the different users? And then, how can I verify if the credentials are working?